# How to paint over normal map

Tags: texture-painting, normal-map

I would like to clean up the edges of a normal map within blender as it's easier to see artefacts.

Unfortunately I cannot find any information on how to actually paint blue (neutral) or any other colour as every blend mode doesn't seem to work as expected.

I'm assuming it's because the colour space is non colour but can't see any solution other than creating a new brush which would defeat the point of using blender to do this at all.

[image: example artefact]

*an area that could easily be painted over.*

[image: value blend mode]

*After using value blend mode, constant falloff, 100% strength using the colour of the surrounded area.*

Comment: you can pick the good color with the eyedropper and paint over the bad area, either in the Image Editor or in the 3D View if you display the normal map on your object

Comment: @moonboots As I said that doesn't work, it produces the outline as shown above in value mode and draws white on mix mode. The normal map is using non colour space, I can draw fine on sRGB or linear.

Comment: could you please share your file (only keep what's necessary)? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: the neutral "flat" color is #8080FF (hex)

Comment: @moonboots Thanks for the help, I figured it out after trying to recreate the issue in a test project.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else who gets confused with this...

blend mode should be mix.

If you use the color picker/eye dropper it won't work (I think due to not being normalised in tangent space).

Setting the color to #8080FF or rgb: 0.5,0.5,1.0 etc will give you the neutral blue colour.

If you need to fill in with the current normal value or manually blend values you need to sample directly from the image by holding s over the normal/colour you want to paint with and then just release s and paint.